# Count occurrences of a group by in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I know this is very simple but I guess I don't know the proper term for what I'm trying to do.  I've got a dataframe like this

```
      word sentiment
1  ability  positive
2  ability  positive
3  ability  positive
4  ability  positive
5 abundant       joy
6 abundant  positive
```

And I'm trying to do a group by and get a count so it would look like this.

```
      word sentiment  Count
1  ability  positive  4
2 abundant       joy  1
3 abundant  positive  1
```

I'm really close I think, here's what I have

```
feelings_summarized <- summarize(group_by(feelings_raw, word, sentiment), mycount=count(feelings_raw, word))
```

Comment: Just use `count` `count(feelings_raw_word, word, sentiment)`

Comment: Oh, it also does group_by.  I was overcomplicating it trying to add it to summarize(group_by()).  Thanks!